# How to tolerate typos with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `query_string`, and I want to be able for my search to tolerate typos. In the query below I typed `The Gren Mile`, but it didn't return any results:

```
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/test
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/test/movies -d '{"title": "The Green Mile"}'
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/test/_refresh
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/test/movies/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "The Gren Mile",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}'
```

It says in the [Elasticsearch docs](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) that `fuzziness` is by default `AUTO` (which tolerates bigger typos as the word gets bigger), so I don't know why it doesn't work. I tried manually setting `fuzziness: 2`, but it didn't work either. Does this option do something else than I think it does?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer as to why the fuzziness parameter isn't working - it didn't work for me either, possibly this is a bug?

However putting the fuzzy operator `~` directly in the string works:

```
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:9200/test/movies/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "The Gren~ Mile",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}'
```

returns the record:

```
{
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.263573,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "test",
      "_type" : "movies",
      "_id" : "AUxq8KE1EKExB5CrkB_W",
      "_score" : 0.263573,
      "_source":{"title": "The Green Mile"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

### Match query

Using fuzziness with a match query works. Either combine the query_string with a match query (to form a single query) or do a match query if the user's original search returns no results.

```
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "The Gren Mile",
        "operator" : "and",
        "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you know how would I generalize it? I'm accepting users's input, so I don't know which ones could be mispelled. When I do a general "fuzzy" type of search, then it's too fuzzy (e.g. doesn't recognize boolean operators). Btw, I read the documentation for `fuzziness` option, and I think it applies only to words which have the `~` fuzzy operator appended.

Comment: You could append `~` to each term before passing to Elasticsearch, possibly a little bit messy. Using fuzziness with a match query seems to work - I'll add it to my answer

Comment: That's a good tip, to run the fuzzy query if the normal one didn't yield any results. I will just have to ignore potential operators, but it's not that big of deal.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work well for me. For example, if people enter phrases, than match query will remove the quotes and treat it as a list of keywords. Also, if someone were to use `-` instead of `NOT`, the match query would strip that too. While this could be a hacky workaround, I would have to put a lot of effort to make this work good enough. I tried putting `~`, but it messes up phrases again, because it's difficult to detect when I'm in quotes inside a regex.